# Putting a floating image in the bottom-right corner for example

Tags: html, css

Basically I want to put a transparent image in the bottom-right corner. I read the questions about top-right, right, and so on. However, I can only apply `margin-top: 100%;` which will put it where I want BUT it shows the scroll bar then and the picture will be really at the bottom, I can't even see it.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
```

Of course you'll need fixed positioning:

```
position: fixed;
```

This will make it stick to the bottom-right corner wherever the user scrolls.

Comment: Puts it to the left, immediately after the content ends. :/

Comment: Even with fixed positioning? Can you post some HTML or a link to your page? Is it in an iframe?

Comment: Works with fixed. Ty. :) | (5 more min until I can accept it. Well.. got another problem with css but I don't even know how to ask it. Maybe I should gather some CSS expert on MSN ? :))

Comment: You're welcome. For more info, read http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp. I don't use MSN :)

Comment: But please do try to write down your question. If you know how to formulate it, you can search for the answer. And in some rare cases, asking a question answers it.

Comment: Honestly, I tried. First I checked Google and then the CSS site. Didn't manage to find it (My google-fu failed once again). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
background-image:url('someurl/image.png');
background-position:right bottom;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Grz, Kris.

Comment: Sorry Kris I already use a background (repeat, etc). Thanks for the suggestion though, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could still put it as a background image of a div you have placed around the rest of your html when needed and give width and height 100%. That would also be a valid solution I think.